# How to use Bootstrap Javascript from Flask-Bootstrap

Tags: python, twitter-bootstrap, flask, jinja2

I am using Flask-Bootstrap.  I add

```
{% extends "bootstrap/base.html" %}
```

to my template to format it using Bootstrap.  How can I use the javascript buttons with bootstrap, since I don't have the js files in my static folder?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The Flask-Bootstrap base template already [includes `jquery.js` and `bootstrap.js`](https://github.com/mbr/flask-bootstrap/blob/282cf952d2a85f23c3c9daba9c940c8156672172/flask_bootstrap/templates/bootstrap/base.html#L26-L29).  You can add your own JavaScript by [overriding the `scripts` block](https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-Bootstrap/basic-usage.html#templates).

```html
{% block scripts %}
    {{ super() }}
    <script>
        // your javascript here
    </script>
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
    <button class="btn btn-success">Hello, World!</button>
{% endblock %}
```